# Explain this weird Razor nullable bool behaviour

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Recently come across this strange behaviour in the Razor Engine in .Net.

We have a property in the ViewModel like

```
bool? Property1 { get; set; }
```

but if we have in if statement like

```
@if(Model.Property1.HasValue)
```

We get an bool does not have Method HasValue error. But the following works

```
@{
 var prop1 = Model.Property1;
}
@if(prop1 != null)
```

Can someone explain WTF is happening because I would expect HasValue to work in the first scenario.  It should be casting to a boolean after evaluating the expression not before as it seems to be doing.

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce this. Have you tried cleaning and then rebuilding your solution? I sometimes encounter strange things in VS related to false errors. Most of the time a simple 'Clean and Rebuild' fixes the issue.

Comment: This is occurring in when we use RazorEngine.Razor.Parse for generating email templates. Using Version 3.0.8.0.